# How do you create a raised tab bar item, like is found in Instagram?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, ios

How do you create a raised item within a UITabBar?

For example, Instagram has this:

[image]

How would I achieve something similar in my application?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

iDevRecipes posted about how to go about recreating exactly that recently, although it's not written by Instagram's developers. Check out [this post](http://idevrecipes.com/2010/12/16/raised-center-tab-bar-button). The basic idea is that you create a custom `UIButton` then add it as a subview above the middle of the tab bar (the middle tab is a dummy tab bar item that does nothing).

Comment: Could you kindly give some more resource link like this!?!?! :D thank you