# Question on iPhone Development Custom UI

Tags: iphone

So on the App Store, what I'm seeing a lot is a custom UI that still looks like the native Apple ones, but is some how "spruced up" in look.  How exactly would I create something like that, as in say a button that is a hexagon or something instead of a rounded rectangle?

Thanks,

VectorWare

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do you create a raised tab bar item, like is found in Instagram?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4549687/how-do-you-create-a-raised-tab-bar-item-like-is-found-in-instagram)

Answer (score 1):

- Draw any image you want, using your favorite art program.
- Don't forget to make pressed and "up" states.
- Create your button (in IB or code.)
- Make the button of type UIButtonTypeCustom (IB or code.)
- In IB, set the button's image to your image.
- Set the image separately for NORMAL and HIGHLIGHTED states (IB or code.)

Example in code:

```
[myButton setImage: myImage forState: UIControlStateNormal];
```

Answer (score 0):

They are probably either subclass' of UIView/UIWhatever or images with a transparent UIButton over top of the image.  Is there something specific you want to implement?

Some examples:
[Subclassing a UIView](http://markuzweb.blogspot.com/2011/05/subclassing-uiview-with-nib-file.html)

[UIView subclass dialog window](http://snipt.net/wayneb250/loading-and-positioning-a-uiview-subclass-dialog-window/)

Comment: nothing really in particular, but thanks for the help anyways

Comment: Anytime!  If you run into trouble implementing something help is available. =)

Comment: No they aren't... It's as easy as setting a background image to the button via it's setBackgroundImage:forState: method.

Comment: @emiliopelaez "No they aren't..." -  so there is not a single App on the App store that subclasses a UIView or has an image behind a transparent button?  Definitively contradicting a phrase that starts with "probably" is just bad form.

Comment: Not as bad having your button be images with invisible buttons over them... That's a terrible practice, I don't see why you would suggest it, even if other apps do it.