# How the instagram application created the view of tabbar in Android Application?

Tags: android

Can anybody guide me how the instagram application created the view of the tabbar in an Android Application? I want to create the same tabbar in my app.

**Screenshot**

---

[image]

Comment: Take a screenshot of the application and post it.

Comment: http://help.instagram.com/customer/portal/articles/95768-there-are-no-photos-in-my-feed  sir please go to that link

Comment: or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8449389/how-do-you-create-a-raised-tab-bar-item-like-the-one-found-in-instagram-with-t   i wanna create same tab bar in android